# Translate content of input field on click with google and php onclick

Tags: php, google-api, google-translate

I'm trying to translate the content in an `input type="text"`field using php.

So far I got this, but I'm a bit lost...

**HTML**:

```
<form id="featured" name="featured" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:200px;" name="ttt" id="ttt" value="<?php echo $description_2_translate ;?>" onclick="translate_text()"/>
<input id="" name="" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
   <?php   
    function translate_text($from_language, $to_language, $description_2_translate){
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($description_2_translate) . '&langpair=' . $from_language . '|' . $to_language));
    $translated_text = $json->responseData->translatedText;

    return $translated_text;
     }?>
```

What am'I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, what happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: @ceejayoz nothing happens. That's the problem...

Comment: Well, you're not calling the `translate_text` function anywhere in the code you've shown. That's where I'd start, unless you've forgotten to share some of your code.

Comment: @ceejayoz I edited the question and you can see I was calling that function on the input field `<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:200px;" name="ttt" id="ttt" value="<?php echo $description_2_translate ;?>" onclick="translate_text()"/>`. Still, nothing happens...

Comment: You can't use `onclick` to call a PHP function directly. That's calling a JavaScript function, which probably doesn't exist. If you want to do that, you need to look into AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", "responseStatus": 403}
```

You are using deprecated API.

Google has closed the free version of translator and requested users to switch to paid Version by 2011.

Comment: Very possible, but OP's not even getting to that issue.